# backbone on event does not work. why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am learning backbone. I am trying to use on event for change. But it gives me this error `Uncaught TypeError: Object function (){ parent.apply(this, arguments); } has no method 'on'` on `line 6`. Below is my code

```
$(function () {
var ford = new Backbone.Model.extend({
    type: 'car',
    color: 'blue'
});
ford.on('change', function () {
    console.log('something changed');
});
ford.set('type', 'truck');
});
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't created an instance of ford yet. Do something like

```
var f = new ford();
```

and then have another function listen to its '[change](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-change)' event.

```
f.on('change', function () {
    console.log('something changed');
});
```

Here, [extend](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-extend) is used to create a constructor function. You have to create objects to bring the model to life.